# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display data between the said date range but it is showing the conversion error. What could be he problem?

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE o_date BETWEEN '28-04-2020' and '04-05-2020'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the standard form for dates:

```
WHERE o_date BETWEEN '2020-04-28' and '2020-05-04'
```

Actually, the above uses ISO standard formats for dates, which almost always (but not always depending on internationalization settings) work in SQL Server.  You can also drop the hyphens for 100% compliance:

```
WHERE o_date BETWEEN '20200428' and '20200504'
```

I would also advise you to use `>=` and `<` -- because such logic works for both dates and date/times:

```
WHERE o_date >= '20200428' and o_date < '20200505'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work too:

```
WHERE o_date BETWEEN '28-Apr-2020' and '04-May-2020'
```